# Adobe Animate errors

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I'm trying to create a token that will disapear when the player touches it. I created an action for the token with the following code

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class TokenFish extends MovieClip
    {
        public var isToken:Boolean;
        public function TokenFish()
        {
            isToken = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However each time I try to run the scene to test it I will get the following errors.

Scene 1, Layer 'game_Stage', Frame 1, Line 5, Column 15 1131: Classes must not be nested.

Scene 1, Layer 'game_Stage', Frame 1    1159: The return statement cannot be used in package initialization code.

Any suggestions will very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to create the class inside of an action which adobe animate doesn't allow. I had to create it as a separate actionscript file.